# Azure DevOps: No module named Office 365

Tags: python, azure-devops, office365, office365api

I am trying to use Office365 Sharepoint in my Python app running as an Azure DevOps pipeline.

In my YAML file I have this:

```
 - script: pip install office365
    displayName: 'Install office365'
 - script: python3 my_script.py
```

I verify that office365 is installing without errors. Yet when my_script runs and imports,

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
```

I get the error: `no module named office365`

Maybe I am missing something about installing dependencies. Why isn't office365 recognized after I just installed it?

Comment: This could be a python version mismatch.  What specific versions of Python are used by `pip` and `python3`?

Comment: this is what I got when I ran ```python3 -m ensurepip```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/dapagent/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (57.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/dapagent/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (22.0.2)

Comment: Okay, so `python3` points to Python 3.9.  What version of Python does `pip` use?  I'm betting it's some other version.

Comment: According to the readout in the comment, 22.0.2

Comment: I think that's the version of pip itself, not the version of Python that pip is linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The office365 library only supports Python 3.8. My Python and Pip environments are 3.9. Even though it is installed, it is not compatible, which may be why it may not be found. Please comment if you know why.